# Is there a way to show the status of a test session on the status bar on Rider?

Tags: user-interface, testing, rider, jetbrains-rider

In Visual Studio with ReSharper it is possible to show a handy icon on its status bar showing the status of a particular test session:

[image]

This icon is very useful, at least for me, because it permits to know if the tests I'm interested in are all green or not all the time, while in Rider I normally have to open the unit tests tool to have the same information. Because of this I have to keep the tool open or reopen it continuously, and that clutters the interface or requires additional effort.

Is there a way to add something similar in Rider?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK that's not possible, at least I couldn't find anything and I never saw Rider sessions with such a feature. But you might [contact JetBrains support](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=97145) to see whether there is a pending feature request.

Answer (score 0):

The feature request ID is [RIDER-58295](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-58295). Subscribe to the issue by pressing the **Watch button** or by upvoting the issue.

You may enable the check box to show notifications for tests in **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Unit Testing** and then make this notification a [sticky balloon type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Notifications.html) in **Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Notifications**. But still it is not giving the exact state of tests.